# Wordpress check if single_cat_title() contains keyword

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to conditionally add a keyword to the end of a title if the category title contains the keyword.

I am using the following code and it is printing `Amish Cookies`, but I would like `Amish Cookies Recipes`.

How can I conditionally add " Recipes" to the end of the title?

```
else if( is_archive() ){
    //echo __('Archive for ', 'recipe') . single_month_title(' ', false);
    echo single_cat_title('Amish ') . single_month_title(' ', false) . (' Recipes'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was a little unclear, but I think this is what you were asking for:

```
<?php
        if( is_archive() ){
            $current_category = single_cat_title("", false); // Get name of current category

            // If current category contains the string "Recipes" don't add it at the end of the name    
            if (strpos($current_category,'Recipes') !== false) {
                echo single_cat_title('Amish '). single_month_title(' ',false); 
            } else {
                echo single_cat_title('Amish ') . single_month_title(' ',false) . (' Recipes'); 
            }

        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hardcoding the prefix with `Amish`  and that does not disrupt your search for the word `Recipes`, then you can write D.R.Y. code by only calling helper function `single_cat_title()` once.

Then you can search for `Recipes` with `strpos()` or `str_contains()` depending on your PHP version.

```
$catTitle = single_cat_title('Amish ', false);
echo $catTitle
     . single_month_title(' ', false)
     . (str_contains($catTitle, 'Recipes') ? ' Recipes' : '');
```

Note, without the 2nd parameter being set to `false`, the helper functions will **print** their payload instead of returning it.  It doesn't make sense to combine `echo` with a function that is already printing its data.